# Attending job talks when you are leaving the department

Tags: etiquette, job-search

I am leaving my current department in the next few weeks. We are currently in the mist of our hiring season and have 12 job talks and campus visits schedule before I leave. None of the positions we are currently trying to fill are explicitly the replacement position to mine and the areas of expertise of the candidates are pretty far removed from mine. We are a large enough department, that there will still be a reasonable sized audience and enough people for the candidates to talk to. Is it inappropriate to skip the job talks and not meet the candidates, unless they specifically ask to meet with me?

Comment: Among other things, I think it depends on why you're leaving. This depends on your department's culture of course, but if were mine: If you're leaving for a department which is obviously much stronger, or to be closer to family, or to solve a two-body problem (or any other reason which does not reflect badly on your current position), I'd be inclined to introduce yourself and freely answer any questions; if you don't much care for your department or the town in which you live, it might be good manners to absent yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to attend all 12!  If anyone questions your absences -- which I doubt they will (people may well not even notice) -- you can say you are up against some deadlines, and also mention needing time for packing and such.

Perhaps you could pick out a small handful of talks that you are sincerely interested in attending.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to answer well without knowing more and I don't think it is appropirate to post more on a public forum!

I think it really depends on your relationships with your colleagues who you are leaving behind. In some situations it is better to absent yourself from situations where people are looking forward to the future of your old department. In other situations your experience may be helpful and it may be supportive to your colleagues who you will leave, but I guess who you want to stay on good terms with and continue to support. (I have not exactly been in this situation before, but similarish ones)